# FirebaseMessaging: Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Getting the error in the title pointing to the line `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_handleNotificationBackground);` in `notification_service.dart`. I thought null check operators are `?` and `!` and I'm not using either one in that line. Why am I getting this error? I can provide more info if needed.

Is there anything I can add to this question to improve it? I can provide more info if needed.

**main.dart:**

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  NotificationService(navigatorKey: navigatorKey);
  
  runApp(MyApp(navigatorKey: navigatorKey,));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key, required this.navigatorKey});

  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;

  return MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ...
    ],
    child: MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      ...
  );
}
```

**notification_service.dart:**

```
class NotificationService {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;

  NotificationService({required this.navigatorKey}) {
    _initialize();
  }

  Future<void> _initialize() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

    // Set up Firebase Cloud Messaging
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_handleNotificationBackground); //ERROR POINTS HERE
    // Initialize the local notifications plugin
    final initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/app_icon');
    final initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification,);
    final initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification,
    );

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      _showNotification(message.data);
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      _handleNotificationResume(message.data);
    });

    }

    Future<void> _handleNotificationBackground(RemoteMessage message) async {
      // Handle notification when app is in the background
      // You can navigate to a specific screen using the payload from the notification
     _handleNotificationResume(message.data);
    }

   Future<void> _handleNotificationResume(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
     // Handle notification when app is resumed from background
     // You can navigate to a specific screen using the payload from the notification
     final route = data['Screen'];

     _navigateToScreen(route: route);
   }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code the prblm can arise from navigator key, you have defined it inside the main function and my guess is that you did not give the key to MaterialApp widget.
As you have not given it to MaterialApp widget and still trying to access it's context which is null causing Navigator push() to throw null error because the context is null.

One more thing after seeing your service class, you have defined the _handleNotificationBackground() inside the NotificationService class, you can not do that you need to define it outside of all class and fn, just define it above you NotificationService class with a annotation of @pragma('vm:entry-point') above the fn like below and do not make it private with _.

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> handleNotificationBackground(RemoteMessage message) async {
  handleMessage(message);
}

class PushNotificationService {
...
}
```

And one more thing define and declare the navigation key outside of main(), so that you can just import it directly without passing it everywhere in parameters

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  NotificationService();
  
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  return MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ...
    ],
    child: MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      ...
  );
}
```

the reason why i am telling you to make it global because as the handleNotificationBackground is outside of all scopes and is global , it will make it easy for you to handle and update code in future.